# Where online can I find a list of all the Hapax Legomena in the Hebrew Bible?

Tags: word-study, linguistics, resource-request

I am looking for a list online of all *Hapax Legomena* in the Hebrew Bible in text format that I can copy and paste into MS Word for further studies.
I need something that's free and is not in a picture format (for example, the list in the [old Encyclopedia Judaica article](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7236-hapax-legomena) has all the Hebrew words as pictures not as text).

Comment: Find an [online Jewish Bible](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16453), and, using the list provided by the *Encyclopedia Judaica* (which contains the book, the chapter, and the verse), find the word which fits the image, and copy-paste it into a document. :-)

Comment: @Lucian I'm sure there's got to be an easier way...

Comment: There was indeed an easier way, but it has been [lost long ago](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167#v19)...

Comment: Try  https://community.logos.com/forums/t/116973.aspx  and  https://community.logos.com/forums/t/147005.aspx  and  https://community.logos.com/forums/t/66705.aspx

Answer (score 1):

https://meafar.blogspot.com/2018/12/unique-readings-hapax-legomena-in.html?m=1

This should be what you are looking for.  It has Hebrew hapax legomena that you can copy.

Comment: Could you please provide a summarization of the link you posted? This will ensure that your answer 1) is maintained in case the link is deleted 2) isn't deleted due to a lack of context for the link. Also, please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.